# I want to show youtube channel live broadcast on my own website with YouTube Data API v3

Tags: ajax, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, live-streaming

I have one website in pure HTML where I want to show YouTube live broadcast from my channel when I am live on YouTube.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2C+snippet%2C+contentDetails&broadcastType=all&mine=true&key={my-key}",
    type: "GET",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

when I am using above code it's showing me login required.

Is there any way I can show my channel live video without login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id,snippet&eventType=completed&channelId={YOUR-CHANNEL-ID}&type=video&key={YOUR-API-KEY}",
   
    async:true,
    crossDomain:true,
    dataType : 'JSON',
    success: function(data){
  $.each(data.items,
            function(i,item)
            { 
    var app = 
    '<div>\
       <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+item.id.videoId+'" width="100%" height="auto" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
      </div>';
                $('.container').append(app);
        }); 
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 
</div>
```

i found a work around  without `OAUTH2.0` using API KEY and channel-ID using `search` API of `YT DATA API`.
you can change the `eventType` to `live` and `completed`.
`items.snippet.id.videoId` for video id and `items.snippet.title` for title of video.
Read documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: Welcome @jigarhalani

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Oauth2 authentication for that API it appears.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/registering_an_application

> The page allows you to create two different types of credentials. However, all of the methods for the YouTube Live Streaming API require OAuth 2.0 authorization. Follow the instructions below to generate OAuth 2.0 credentials.
>
> OAuth 2.0: Your application must send an OAuth 2.0 token with any request that accesses private user data. Your application sends a client ID and, possibly, a client secret to obtain a token. You can generate OAuth 2.0 credentials for web applications, service accounts, or installed applications.
>
> See the Creating OAuth 2.0 credentials section for more information.
>
> API keys: You have the option of including an API key with a request. The key identifies your project and provides API access, quota, and reports.
>
> Note that all of the methods for the YouTube Live Streaming API require OAuth 2.0 authorization. For that reason, you need to follow the instructions above for generating OAuth 2.0 credentials. If you want, you can also send an API key, but it is not necessary.